# Get value for Finder Application Version column

Tags: applescript

I need to be able to read the 'version' of my application (aka Osirix) and compare it to an expected value.  I know how to do the comparison but I am not sure how to read the version now.

I think I could do this by reading it from the Get Info window, or reading it from the Version column in Finder/Application column

I cannot seem to find examples to modify for either option

`set ReadAppVersion to value of version of application "Osirix"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply delete `value of`

```
set ReadAppVersion to version of application "Osirix"
```